# Vue js didn't send select option value

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2

i can send single select option value by this method but i can't send multiple option value . if i remove select2 js from mounted and inside methide then it works fine.

> we can use ajax retrieval too ?

here is my code below :

```
<script>

        var app = new Vue({
            el:'#stock',
            mounted:function(){
                    $( function() {
                        $(".m-select2").select2({
                            width:'100%',
                            placeholder: "Select a value",

                        })
                    } )
            },
            data:{
                ck:false,
                stocks:[
                    {
                        product:'',
                        qty:'',
                        price:''
                    }
                ]
            },
            methods:{
                addStock(){
                    $( function() {
                        $(".m-select2").select2({
                            width:'100%',
                            placeholder: "Select a value",

                        })
                    } ),
                        this.stocks.push({
                            product:'',
                            qty:'',
                            price:''
                        })
                },
                remove(index){
                    this.stocks.splice(index,1)
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

@blade

```
 <select v-model="stock.product" class="form-control m-select2" name="sku_id[]" id="">
                                            @foreach($skus as $sku)
                                                <option value="{{$sku->id}}">{{$sku->Product()->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For possible data sources you can take a look at their documentation: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

Quick example would be:

`var data = {{ $skus }};
$(".m-select2").select2({
    width:'100%',
    placeholder: "Select a value",
    data: data
})`

And html would be:

`<select v-model="stock.product" class="form-control m-select2" name="sku_id[]" id=""></select>`

Comment: i am talking about multiple row

Comment: not working .. can you send me full code ? i can't use this line `var data = {{ $skus->toArray() }};`

Comment: How are you getting `skus`? From which source?

Comment: i am getting skus from my controller in my @blade

Comment: can we use api/ajax ?

Comment: Can you include that part too in your question? To answer your question, we can use `ajax` retrieval too if u want to

Comment: added ... check it

Comment: Check the updated code and also take a look at the link I posted, because no one is obligated to give you the full code to the fix, but rather guide you so you fix it urself